# Laravel 5 pass variable from link in view to route without showing in the URL bar

Tags: laravel, variables, url, laravel-5, routes

I try to explain a situation as best as I can and I would like to
know what solution would you adopt in this case.
Let's say we have a table in the DB with products.
Each product has a id, name and other irrelevant properties.
I need to have in the address bar this kind of URL:

```
http://website.bla/products/mickeymouse
```

where mickeymouse is a customized name, pratically is taken from the name
field in the database but customized to be more URL friendly.

Now, to manage it, I need a route that will call the controller that will
call the new view of the product. And that's the problem. Since mickeymouse
is a customized name, even if I pass it to the route, I cant really find it
in the database through the controller, cause it's almost impossible to
retrieve the original name.
So I thought I could pass the ID which is possible to do, but the url would
become sorta:

```
http://website.bla/products/255/mickeymouse
```

with 255 as example id and I would like to avoid to show the product id in the URL

Is it possible in laravel 5 to pass a variable (ex:id) from a simple link
to a route without showing it in the address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) package for Laravel. It's the easiest way to do what you want to do.

It's easy-to-use package which will automatically create SEO friendly slugs for you from any column in a table. Also, it adds methods like `finBySlug($id)`:

```
$list = MyList::findBySlug($id);
```

Comment: Probably and unfortunately it's the only way, apart from creating a new tab with the beautified URLs in a id relation with the main tab. I've hoped there was a less intrusive solution trick but I knew it was quite impossible. Thanks.